# How do i give the primeng autocomplete placeholder a float label function? Angular 9 + PrimeNg

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

So i've built a dropdown with the autocomplete of primeng and i have a problem. When i click into my dropdown, to choose some data, the placeholder just disappears but i want it to go up instead like my text input fields do. But i'm confused since my dropdown hasn't got any real input or label tag.

My dropdowns most outer div has the class "ui-float-label". And inside that i have a div with the class "ui-fluid". And finally inside the "ui-fluid" there is my p-autocomplete which looks like this.

```
<p-autoComplete
                [(ngModel)]="valueOfSingleSelection"
                [suggestions]="selectionResults"
                (completeMethod)="search($event)"
                field="label"
                [placeholder]="selectorProperties.labelMls"
                [minLength]="1"
                [dropdown]="true"
                [disabled]="!selectorProperties.enabled"
                required
                (onBlur)="setRequiredOnBlur()">
```

So how do i make the placeholder go up? i know noob question but i appreciate every help i can get, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use a Float Label, here is the documentation :
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/floatlabel

Usage is as follows :

```
    <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
        <span class="p-float-label">
            <p-autoComplete inputId="autocomplete" [(ngModel)]="value2" [suggestions]="filteredCountries" (completeMethod)="searchCountry($event)" field="name"></p-autoComplete>
            <label for="autocomplete">AutoComplete</label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Basically you warp your autoComplete and your label in a `class="p-float-label"` container